# Is there a way for me to check that an element is not 'loaded' yet in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a piece of javascript/jquery that is an event listener, waiting for an element to load:

```
$("#download-iframe").on("load", function() {

    alert("Download iframe loaded.  src attribute value: " + $(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Right now this alert will pop up once the script in the `src` attribute is done loading/running.

I want to show a progress bar of sorts that increments slowly, but I want it to do thins only as long as the `$("#download-iframe")` element is not yet loaded.

Is there a way to check in an if statement if the element is loaded yet or not?

```
function showProgress() {

    var oneMinute = 60000; // One minute in milliseconds
    var maxTime = 10 * oneMinute; // Maximum time in minutes, 10 minutes
    var progress = 5;
    var increment = 5;

    $("#show-progress").attr("aria-valuenow", increment);
    $("#show-progress").css("width", increment + '%');

    var scriptProgress = setInterval( function() {

        progress += increment;
        if (progress <= 100 && /* ALSO CHECK FOR ELEMENT NOT YET LOADED HERE */) {

            $("#show-progress").attr("aria-valuenow", progress);
            $("#show-progress").css("width", progress + '%');
        }
        else {

             $(".progress").addClass("hidden");
             clearInterval(scriptProgress);
        }

    }, oneMinute / 10);

}
```

I am using twitter bootstrap's progress bars. the src script being run is a POST ajax URL that is not an upload/download so I can't use an AJAX progress eventListener. I want to give the user the appearance of something happening, a feedback of some kind.

If the iframe src is loaded prior to the progress bar reaching 100% incrementally, I want it to jump to 100% and then show the result of the PHP script.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Why not set a flag in `load()`

```
var loaded = false;
$("#download-iframe").on("load", function() {
    loaded = true;
    alert("Download iframe loaded.  src attribute value: " + $(this).attr("src"));
});
```

and then in the `if` statement

```
if (progress <= 100 && loaded)
```

Comment: I might have other problems in my script I'm finding. I will try to mark this as correct/it worked as soon as I get the kinks fixed!

Comment: @MaggieB. , if the problem may be related to my solution, let me know so we can try to work it out. What is the problem? An exception?

Comment: My alert in the on load function is not popping up anymore. I did some other button mashing within the minute or so before I saw your response so it might be related to that instead.

No errors in the console or otherwise, just no alert anymore before the save file popup comes up.

Comment: @MaggieB., try pressing `F12` and go to the *networking* profiler. Track the request to your iframe source and see its response. This way, you can rule out its not a problem from the backend

Comment: `F12` opened up Firebug Lite in my Chrome browser and I didn't see any tab/content that showed networking. Maybe I still don't understand what I'm looking for, I usually use the Chrome Developer Tools if that helps.

Comment: @MaggieB., sorry, not *networking* but *network*. Do you see that tab?

Comment: @MaggieB., do you have a live link to the site?